# Azure Media Service - Streaming Units charging - per day or per month?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

How are Streaming Units is being charged; per day or per month?

[Media Services pricing page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/) shows:

*~ $4.48/day ($139/mo)*

*Billing is prorated daily based on 31 days per month.*

[image]

while [pricing calculator page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) is based on only per month calculation.

[image]

Thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's prorated daily.  So as soon as you turn it on, you are charged for the first day.  The pricing calculator is only showing the monthly fee and not allowing you set it by day.